# How to get sessions count on every day at last 30 days using PHP client library

Tags: php, session, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using php library to contact with Google analytics reporting api, 
I used this code  to get sessions count:

```
$analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:' . $profileId,
    '30daysAgo',
    'today',
    'ga:sessions'
    );
```

the result is one value along 30 days, i want to get array consists of every day and sessions count.

Comment: You need to add date as a dimension to the query, then the number of session will be displayer per date. I'm reasonably sure this is a duplicate, so I'll look around a bit in the old question before writing an answer.

Comment: Ok thanks,i was confused and the solution as you mentioned , i will post my working code,thank you Eike.

Answer (score 0):

The wanted code is :

```
$optParams = array(
        'dimensions' => 'ga:date') ;
    return $analytics->data_ga->get(
        'ga:' . $profileId,
        '30daysAgo',
        'today',
        'ga:sessions',
        $optParams
    )
```